# Cors in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cors, jira

I have to make a request to the Jira sever, i have used angular Js and html. I am getting the following error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/project. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I cant change any server settings. How can i enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have added SimpleCORSFilter.java file. Still problem is not solved.

When i just take the URL, Json response is dispalyed. when called the URL using Angular JS above error is showing up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin if you can't change any server settings.

Comment: You can't ... please google the error. You will find volumes of information about cors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't really control it from your side, that's the whole point.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work). The response from the server must return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. So... talk with your server dudes.

Comment: Is it not possible using any of SimpleCORSFilter files?

Comment: I assume it should help since it's on the server side, but I see you're still not getting the desired outcome so you must provide more of your code. I looked at some related angular+cors questions here which can provide help but you must share more code before